# varnish cache apache virtual hosts on 2 servers

Tags: varnish

We have 2 Apache servers serving different content and make use of virtual hosts. On one server we have a blog, wiki and forum, and on the other we have a helpdesk and static page. We currently have one squid reverse proxy on a 3rd server in front of both.

We are looking at replacing squid reverse proxy with varnish.

I have been unable to find anything that works, and [varnish, apache and namebased virtual host with own ip addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111317/varnish-apache-and-namebased-virtual-host-with-own-ip-addresses) does not work.

It is a Centos 6 server we are installing varnish on.

Does anyone have  any configurations that possibly work?

EDIT TO ADD: 
Ok Finally figured it out. Below please find a complete script, for posterity.

On server1 is: 
registration.test.co.za
oldforum.test.co.za

On Server2 is: 
forum.test.co.za
blog.test.co.za

```
    acl internal_net {
        "localhost";
        "192.168.1.0"/24;

}
backend server1 {
  .host = "192.168.1.101";
  .port = "80";
}
backend server2 {
    .host = "192.168.1.102";
    .port = "80";
}

# Respond to incoming requests
sub vcl_recv {
######BACKENDS#####################
#
#SERVER1
#
if (req.http.host == "registration.test.co.za$") {
set req.backend = server1;


} else if (req.http.host ~ "oldforum.test.co.za$") {
        set req.backend = server1;
#
#SERVER2
#
} else if (req.http.host ~ "forum.test.co.za$") {
        set req.backend = server2;


} else if (req.http.host ~ "blog.test.co.za$") {
        set req.backend = server2;
}

        # Allow purge only from internal users
        if (req.request == "PURGE") {
                if (!client.ip ~ internal_net) {
                        error 405 "Not allowed.";
                }
                return (lookup);

}
# Non-RFC2616 or weird requests
        if (req.request != "GET" &&
                req.request != "HEAD" &&
                req.request != "PUT" &&
                req.request != "POST" &&
                req.request != "TRACE" &&
                req.request != "OPTIONS" &&
                req.request != "DELETE") {
                return (pass);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post you mentioned that "does not work" seems perfectly fine. You just make 2 backends in the varnish configuration and then select backend based on host requested.

If you can not get it to work you would need to post details of your setup and the configuration that does not work to get further help.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have put this on the back burner for, but will update query in a few months time